# no row at position 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the following code snippet:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
    {
        string catid = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
        Query1 = "select senderfirstname from messages where senderid='" + catid + "'";
        adap = new SqlDataAdapter(Query1, con);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables["messages"];
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Session["table"] = dr["senderfirstname"].ToString();       
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "error";
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error as:

> There is no row at position 0.

I have the same query in sql server, but my table has contents for this query.

Comment: Do you hate vowels? Are you a filthy vowel-hater?  For shame!  For. Shame.

Comment: I took the freedom to insert vowels randomly into the words. Looks much nicer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *not* loading data in to the `DataSet`. You have to call [SqlDataAdapter.Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to load the data in the `DataSet`. Also assign the row in the condition where you check that `Rows` count is greater then zero for not getting **exception** when not row exists.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
     if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
     {
         string catid = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
         Query1 = "select senderfirstname from messages where senderid='" + catid + "'";
         adap = new SqlDataAdapter(Query1, con);
         adap.Fill(ds);
         DataTable dt = ds.Tables["messages"];

         if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
              DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
              Session["table"] = dr["senderfirstname"].ToString();       
         }
         else
         {
            Label1.Text = "error";
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your updated code below

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
  if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
  {
   string catid = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
   Query1 = "select senderfirstname from messages where senderid='" + catid + "'";
   adap = new SqlDataAdapter(Query1, con);
   DataTable dt = ds.Tables["messages"];

   if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
      DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
      Session["table"] = dr["senderfirstname"].ToString();
   }
   else
   {
      Label1.Text = "error";
   }
}
```